# JQuery tooltip position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have been working on a simple tool tip (see fiddle below), but am having some positioning problems. I would like the tip to appear centered and above the link that is clicked. At the moment the top left corner is positioned at the mouse click. I tried to offset this position by half of the tooltip but to no success.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ricco/CBf4C/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the changes at http://jsfiddle.net/CBf4C/3/

You need to get the position of the clicked element (*use [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/)*), get the dimensions of the tooltip with [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) and [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) and then calculate based on these..

the actual code is

```
$('a[title]').click(function(e) {

    //fadetooltip and display information
    $('body').append('<div class="tooltip"><div class="tipBody"></div></div>');
    tip = $(this).attr('title');
    var tooltip = $('.tooltip'); // store a reference to the tooltip to use it later
    tooltip.fadeTo(300, 0.9).children('.tipBody').html( tip );


    // calculate position of tooltip
    var el = $(this),
        pos = el.position(), // get position of clicked element
        w = el.outerWidth(), // get width of clicked element, to find its center
        newtop = pos.top - tooltip.outerHeight() , // calculate top position of tooltip
        newleft = pos.left + (w/2) - (tooltip.outerWidth()/2); // calculate left position of tooltip

    //set position
    $('.tooltip').css('left', newleft )  ;
    $('.tooltip').css('top',  newtop );

    hideTip = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/CBf4C/15/ - see this.

Comment: Please include an inline explanation. the external links could break later or evolve.

Answer (score 0):

See the changes I've made here: http://jsfiddle.net/CBf4C/9/