# Tooltip appearing at the bottome of the page in chrome but not in IE

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Hi i have a tooltip that is appearing at the bottom of the page. It should just appear after the mouspointer. It is currently working in IE but not in Chrome!

Here is my html code

```
    <div style="width:958px; margin:auto">
      <div id="diy_content">

         <div> 
            <a class="tip_trigger" href="shttp://www.purplecoffer.com" 
              onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
              onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('purplecoffer','','http://beta.brownbag.ph/diy/mini-banners/purplecoffer.jpg',1)">
            <img src="http://beta.brownbag.ph/diy/mini-  banners/purplecoffer_2.jpg" name="purplecoffer" width= "150px" height = "100px"border="0">
            <span class="tip" style="width: 400px;"><img src="http://beta.brownbag.ph/diy/mini-banners/purplecoffer.jpg" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;" alt="" />
            Purple Coffer <br/>
            Apparel and Clothing <br/>
            VISIT: www.purplecoffer.com         
            </span>
            </a>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
/*--Tooltip Styles--*/
.tip {
    position:absolute;    
    z-index:1000;
    color: #fff;
    background:#1d1d1d;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.tip_trigger .tip { display:none; }
```

And here is my function

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //Tooltips
        $('.tip_trigger').each(function() {        
        var tip = $(this).find('.tip');

        $(this).hover(
            function() { tip.appendTo('body');},
            function() { tip.appendTo(this); }
        ).mousemove(function(e) {
            var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
            var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
            var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
            var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip

            //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
            var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
            //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
            var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

            if ( tipVisX < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
                mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
            } if ( tipVisY < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
                mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
            } 
            tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex  });

        });         
        });
});
```

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. Mb, there's something in console? Try pressing F12 and check out the "Console" tab. If there's anything like errors you can put it down here or try to figure out for urself.

Comment: I got this error from chrome what does this mean? Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setProperty'

Comment: There's link next to error, which will lead you to the string of code, where the error appears. Go click it and debug ;)

Comment: Hi @VladislavQulin Thanks for the reply i already fixed the error but still doesnt work in chrome.. in IE and firefox it does work :(

Comment: Finally got it working using this code in the mousemove function
`$('.tip').css('left', $(this).position().left+($(this).width()/2)-($('.tooltip').outerWidth()/2))  ;
   $('.tip').css('top',  $(this).position().top-$('.tooltip').outerHeight());`
-from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491197/jquery-tooltip-position?rq=1